# Rmagick 2.16.0 not building under Windows with MINGW64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, mingw-w64

I have this RoR system and I am trying to run a `bundle install` on Windows 7 64bits with MINGW64. One of the gems I use is rmagick and its native extensions are not being built.

[image]

I have devkit correctly installed and some other gems with native extensions (like nokogiri) are being built perfectly. Then I believe this is happening because i don't have some library/headers to perform this compilation correctly.

It happens that I have almost no experience with Windows development. In fact I am trying to make this run exactly to learn more about RoR development under Windows. On a day to day basis I use only Linux (Debian 8 or Slackware 14), but I really don't like to be limited in choice and would really like to learn a bit more about Windows development.

Do someone know what I need to install and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rmagick relies on imagemagick *below* version 7.
Redmine has a pretty good guide on installing it for windows that should help your lib issues.
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_install_rmagick_gem_on_Windows